# Is there any way I can get a sorted array of key from key value of the object

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

I have an object which have keys with value.

```
{
"qwertyuasddf":2,
"asdfghsdfffk":3,
"zxcvvnbvcxxm":1
}
```

expected result

```
["zxcvvnbvcxxm","qwertyuasddf","asdfghsdfffk"]
```

Comment: use `Object.entries` and `array.sort` - to be clear, you want the sort to be based on the value of the keys, it's not a case of reverse alphabetical sort order ... so, `Object.entries(obj).sort(([,a],[,b])=>a-b).map(([k])=>k)`

Comment: or just sort the `keys()` and skip the `map()`... `Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => obj[a] - obj[b]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
[Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries),
[array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and
[array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const obj = { "qwertyuasddf":2, "asdfghsdfffk":3, "zxcvvnbvcxxm":1 };

const result = Object.entries(obj).sort(([,a],[,b])=>a-b).map(([k])=>k)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = { "qwertyuasddf":2, "asdfghsdfffk":3, "zxcvvnbvcxxm":1 }
const sorted_keys = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1).map(e => e[0]);
```